# Kial "plej" postulas difinan artikolon?

Tags: article

Mi ĉiam vidas "la plej bona", "la plej maljuna", sed kun "pli" ĝi estas nur "pli bona", "pli juna", ktp. Kial "plej" ne funkcias sen "la" kun adjektivoj (kvankam ĝi funkcias tiel kun adverboj)? Aŭ ĉu estas esceptoj?

Answer (score 5):

Ne estas unu respondo al tiu demando, sed kelkaj fenomenoj:

1. En la latinidaj lingvoj, antaŭ superlativo aŭtomate aperas artikolo, ĉar ili ne havas vorton por "plej", sed fakte diras "la pli". Povas esti, ke tiu kutimo parte ankoraŭ influas Esperanton.
2. Certe tia influo estas en la komenca tempo, kiam Zamenhof uzis tre ofte *la* kun superlativo, eĉ kiam temis pri adverbo: "oni sin sentas la plej oportune". Ĉi-lasta uzo nun plene malaperis el la lingvouzo.
3. Kiel ĝuste rimarkigas [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/la/specialaj_uzoj.html#i-9ps), tamen en tre multaj okazoj la uzo de *la* estas tute prava, ĉar temas ja pri unu specifa, individua afero, kiun oni komparas al ĉiuj aliaj, kaj tio kompreneble bone kongruas kun la individuiga, specifiga signifo de la artikolo.

Ekz. *El ĉiuj amikoj Petro estas la plej malnova. = tiu unu plej malnova amiko* ks.*

Se vi mem dubas, ĉu meti artikolon, ĉu ne, tiam ne metu ĝin. Oni laŭ Z uzu la artikolon nur en okazoj de klara bezono.

*Redakto: En tia frazo do ne iel la superlativo, sed la subkomprenata substantivo (*amiko*) postulas la artikolon.

Answer (score 2):

Ne, *plej* ne postulas difinan artikolon. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj sen *la*, kiujn mi trovis en [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/pli_plej.html#i-mkn):

> *Aŭgusto estas mia plej amata filo.*
>
> *Li ekaŭdis bruan tonon, kiu povis ektimigi la koron eĉ de plej kuraĝa viro.*
>
> *Plej profunde en la koro li kaŝis sian malĝojon.*
>
> *Plej bone estos, se mi prenos droŝkon!*

Comment: La unua frazo ne estas decidiga, ĉar ĝi enhavas _mia_, post kiu ĉiam manku _la_, la du lastaj havas adverban superlativon, ĉe kiu _la_ estus arkaismo.

Answer (score 2):

Jen treege interesa demando! Kiel skribis Cyril, mi kredas ke iel temas pri Latinida influo. Difinecon eblas krei ne nur per ”la”, sed ankaŭ per posedaj pronomoj (kaj kelkaj tabelvortoj, ekz-e ”tiu”). 
Kiom da difineco povas porti ne-artikoloj varias inter lingvoj, ekzemple ”mia amiko” estas *mi amigo* Hispane sed ”la mia amiko” Itale (*il mio amico*) kaj Katalune (*el meu amic*).
Kiel Bertilo [notas](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/aliaj.html), tiu ĉi ŝancelo ankaŭ ekzistas E-e: *Tiu ĉi libro estas mia. / Tiu ĉi libro estas la mia.* Ĉu temas pri nacilingva influo aŭ pri tre delikata gramatika diferenco – kiel opinias Bertilo – mi ne scias.

Ni prenu ekzemple la frazon

> Li estas mia plej bona amiko.

La vorto ”mia” indikas difinecon kaj ni ne dubas ke temas pri iu specifa persono el pluraj nespecifaj.

Do, nun ni forigu je ”mia”:

> Li estas plej bona amiko.

Je mia lingva orelo nun mankas io. La vorto ”plej” ne kunportas sufiĉe da difineco, kaj mi volus ŝanĝi la frazon al

> Li estas tre bona amiko.

Ŝajne ”plej” – iom ironie – ne estas sufiĉe forta en Esperanto por memstare aldoni difinecon (eĉ se teorie tio belus). Samkiel la posedaj pronomoj de la Itala kaj Kataluna, ĝi bezonas apogon de l’ artikolo.

Comment: Simila ”ŝancelo” ekzistas ankaŭ ekster Latinidaj lingvoj. Kelkaj Norvegoj diras ”far min” (patro mia), dum aliaj diras ”faren min” (la patro mia). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ŝajnas al mi ke temas pri skema kutimo: se "la  " taŭgas, "la plej   " ankaŭ taŭgas, kvankam "la" estas balasta. "Plej" jam liveras la difinan sencon.

Sen "la", ŝajnas orele ke io mankas ĉar la sama frazo sen "plej" nepre bezonas "la".

"La bona vino" ne egalas al "bona vino". Ni do atendas "la"-on en "la plej bona vino" por ne rompi la skemon.